# How to check for null in collection

Tags: c#, linq

How is it possible there is a null in the collection? When I iterate the collection, item is null.

I was using linq and it was throwing the exception. So I did a double foreach. How can I check in linq?

https://ibb.co/dLAJJx

```
            //var list = from?.SelectMany(x => x.Media)
        //    .Select(x => new Media { Height = x.Height, Href = x.Href, Width = x.Width });

        //return list;            


        List<Media> list = new List<Media>();
        if (from == null) return null;
        foreach (var item in from )
        {
            if (item.Media == null) return null;
            foreach (var media in item.Media)
            {
                list.Add(new Media { Height = media.Height, Href = media.Href, Width = media.Width });
            }
        }

        return list;
```

Comment: somewhere, `null` must be added to the list. This is a valid operation. debug your code for places where `from` is populated. instead of `return null` write `continue;` because what your code currently does is aborting everything instead of skipping the nulls.

Comment: @dlatikay thank you. I will check to see where it is being added and prevent. Ok, I will use continue.

Answer (score 4):

You could apply where clause to eliminate null items;

```
from = from.Where(x => x != null);
```

And if you want to check null control for `Media` property, too;

```
from = from.Where(x => x != null && x.Media != null);
```

Also, don't return the method in the loop, continue with iteration by `continue`

```
if (item.Media == null) continue;
```

Comment: Thank you I  will add the check and use continue

Answer (score 2):

Consider this approach:

```
var list = from?
    .SelectMany(x => x.Media)?
    .Where(z = z != null)?
    .Select(x => new Media { Height = x.Height, Href = x.Href, Width = x.Width })?
    .ToList();
```

The `?` will ensure the code works if `from` is `null`. The `Where` will strip out any individual `null` entries (which seems to be your issue).